# Name of this $\chi^2$ post-hoc test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, post-hoc

I conducted the post-hoc analysis for my chi-square test described in these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krLz0GK3uwg (part 2)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rp0qorrPXA0 (part 3)

I was wondering if anyone knew the specific name of the test, or had a recommendation for how I should describe it in my write-up.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, this approach has no proper name. When we used it we cited Sharpe (2015), which includes references to sources that discusses the approach (look for the Calculating Residuals section). This was how we presented it in our article:

> We again used a X2 to test for differences between adults and
>   children. A significant result was found, suggesting that adults and
>   children differ in the range of assessments they tend to receive,
>   X2(3) = 23.7, p < 0.001. In order to determine where these differences
>   lie, we followed the approach described by Sharpe (2015) and examined
>   the standardised residual values for each combination shown in Table 4
>   (i.e., a z-score measuring the difference between what was observed
>   and what would be expected if there was no true difference between
>   adults and children; Agresti, 2007, p. 38). These were calculated
>   using the formula:
>
> $$\text{standardised residual} = \frac{(\text{observed} - \text{expected})}{\sqrt{\text{residual cell variance}}}$$
>
> For the four combinations shown in Table 4, absolute values of the
>   residuals were found to be 1.5, 4.5, 0.5, and 3.6. As these are
>   z-scores, any value greater than 2 is likely to reflect a significant
>   difference. Significant differences were found to lie between the
>   frequencies of adults and children receiving an assessment containing
>   only clinical history and contextual information, and between the
>   frequencies of adults and children receiving all three components.

Rutherford, M., McKenzie, K., McClure, I., Forsyth, K., O’Hare, A., McCartney, D., & Finlayson, I. (2016). A national study to investigate the clinical use of standardised instruments in autism spectrum disorder assessment of children and adults in Scotland. Research in Autism Spectrum Disorders, 29, 93-100.

Sharpe, D. (2015). Your Chi-Square Test is Statistically Significant: Now What?. Practical Assessment, Research & Evaluation, 20(8), 2.